# HTTP post 'error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv 1 alert protocol version'

Tags: delphi, indy10

i have googled/tested various option changes but am still getting the error and guessing that i have something off. in a dll this is the code. i have used the restdebugger from embarcadero to test that it actually works (values/url/response) Returns a JSON response with a bearer token.

```
      objHTTP := TidHTTP.Create(nil);
      objHTTP.Response.KeepAlive := True;
      objHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
      objHTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/html,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
      objHTTP.HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
      objHTTP.ConnectTimeout := 60 * 1000;
      objHTTP.ReadTimeout := 5 * 60 * 1000;
      objHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      objHTTP.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';
      objHTTP.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';
      objHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
      objHTTPIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create();
      objHTTPIOHandler.ReadTimeout := 5 * 60 * 1000;
      objHTTPIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
//      objHTTPIOHandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
      objHTTPIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned; //(sslmUnassigned, sslmClient, sslmServer, sslmBoth)
      objHTTPCompressor := TIdCompressorZLib.Create();
      objHTTP.IOHandler := objHTTPIOHandler;
      objHTTP.Compressor := objHTTPCompressor;
    
      _ss := TStringStream.Create('client_id=' + 'clien_id' + '&'
                                          + 'client_secret=' + 'client_secret' + '&'
                                          + 'scope=' + 'api',
                                            TEncoding.UTF8);
      try
        try
          _ss.Position := 0;
          result := objHTTP.Post('https://dev.corporate.com/oauth2/test/v1/token', _ss);
        except
          on E: Exception do
            Result := 'Error';
    //        ShowMessage('Error on request: ' + #13#10 + e.Message);
        end;
      finally
        _ss.Free;
      end;
      FreeAndNil(objHTTPIOHandler);
      FreeAndNil(objHTTPCompressor);

  FreeAndNil(objHTTP);
```

i looked at my projects connection to the server and the rest debugger and off the top i see that my project is tls 1.0 and the rest debugger is tls 1.2

I removed the sslversions part and set the method to tls1.2 but fiddler still shows as 1.0.  Will i need to update indy before that changes?

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)
Random: 79 FE 3A F5 D6 1F 8F AA BE 10 DB 53 73 DB 08 97 BC 18 75 A6 8A 8C 60 69 FB D5 8B 93 C4 91 4B 75
"Time": 5/17/2100 7:42:33 PM
SessionID: empty
Extensions: 
    server_name dev.corporation.com
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0], ansiX962_compressed_prime [0x1], ansiX962_compressed_char2 [0x2]
    supported_groups    secp256r1 [0x17], secp521r1 [0x19], unknown [0x1c], unknown [0x1b], secp384r1 [0x18], unknown [0x1a], secp256k1 [0x16], sect571r1 [0xe], sect571k1 [0xd], sect409k1 [0xb], sect409r1 [0xc], sect283k1 [0x9], sect283r1 [0xa]
    SessionTicket   empty
    heartbeat_rfc_6520  01
Ciphers: 
    [C014]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C00A]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0039]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0037]  TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0036]  TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C00F]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C005]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0088]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
    [0087]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
    [0086]  TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
    [0085]  TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
    [0084]  TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0033]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0031]  TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0030]  TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C00E]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C004]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [009A]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
    [0099]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
    [0098]  TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
    [0097]  TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
    [0045]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    [0044]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    [0043]  TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    [0042]  TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    [0096]  TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
    [0041]  TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    [0007]  SSL_RSA_WITH_IDEA_SHA
    [C011]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [C007]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [C00C]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [C002]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
    [C012]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
    [C008]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
    [0016]  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0010]  SSL_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [000D]  SSL_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [C00D]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
    [C003]  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [00FF]  TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

Response from restdebugger:

```
A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 63 3C 8B E3 90 77 7F 1A 0F 0D B8 8C 6D 55 C8 97 9B AC 37 75 01 74 65 8B 14 A3 C4 47 6B 9A 8E 75
"Time": 12/21/2090 9:23:15 AM
SessionID: F4 1C 00 00 8D B2 EA 6F 00 37 9B 61 38 78 2E 8E 19 28 BD B9 C8 BE CC 63 70 3E 76 72 60 4E 61 EA
Extensions: 
    server_name dev.corporation.com
    status_request  OCSP - Implicit Responder
    supported_groups    x25519 [0x1d], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    signature_algs  rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_sha1, dsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
    SessionTicket   empty
    extended_master_secret  empty
    renegotiation_info  00
Ciphers: 
    [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C030]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02F]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C028]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C00A]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C014]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [009D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [009C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [003D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    [003C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

Comment: You did not say which version of Delphi or Indy you are using. For instance, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` in versions of Indy 10 prior to 2016 did not use SNI in the TLS handshake, which could cause the kind of error you are seeing. Are you using an Indy version that shipped with your IDE (which one?), or are you using an updated version from Indy's GitHub repo?

Comment: On a side note: the preferred way to send an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request is to post a `TStringList` instead of a `TStringStream`. Also, the SSLIOHandler's `SSLOptions.Method` and `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` properties are mutually exclusive, so use one or the other, not both (preferably only `SSLVersions`).

Comment: delphi 10.2 indy 10.6.2.5366  i will alter the string stream to stringlist to see if that helps. thank you.

Comment: Switching to `TStringList` will not fix the TLS error. It is just that `TIdHTTP` has logic in place to format a `TStringList` into an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request for you. In any case, Delphi 10.2 was released in 2017, so `TIdSSLIOHanlderSocketOpenSSL` *should* include SNI in the TLS handshake. Can you provide a capture of the TLS handshake? However, you are using 5 year old versions, have you tried upgrading yet? If you can't upgrade Delphi, you can at least upgrade Indy. Instructions are in the Wiki on Indy's GitHub repo: https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/wiki/Updating-Indy

Comment: You already stated that in your question's title. There is no diagnostic info provided to troubleshoot your issue

Comment: sorry IT security is very tight and i don't have permissions to remove/add anything related to version. as for a TLS Handshake not sure where to get that but i can google it

Comment: "*as for a TLS Handshake not sure where to get that*" - You can uae a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide that info , don't put it in comments

Answer (score -3):

Assign the correct ssliohandler
BONEHEADED coding error. there are a set of global variables to http, ssliohandler and compressor. I created the above with its own variables of the same type with different names. copy/paste/edit. i added all the obj... to the front of the variables EXCEPT when doing the assign objhttp.handler := httpiohanlder; the httpiohandler is a global var and i looked at that code for like a week off and on. Butchered it nine different ways and nothing worked. finally after a couple of beers i actually looked at code and saw the issue then changed it to objhttpiohandler that was created in that function scope. Really a stupid idiotic mistake. from copy/paste/edit.
So the code shown now is fixed and works. Thanks to Remy for making me realize/understand that Indy works fine when used properly.

Comment: Please elaborate, otherwise this "answer" virtually helps nobody.